# Mysqli week, el comienzo de semana aveces no arranca en domingo

Tags: sql, mysqli

tengo el siguiente problema, hice una consulta para traer el numero de semana, y el comienzo y final de la misma, pero como se ve en la imagen me toma cualquier valor. Que puede ser?

```
SELECT  SUM(cheques_importe) as 'total',week(cheques_fecha) as fechaSemana, (SELECT cheques_fecha from cheques_ventas where week(cheques_fecha) = fechaSemana ORDER BY cheques_fecha asc limit 1) as desde,  DATE_ADD( (SELECT cheques_fecha from cheques_ventas where week(cheques_fecha) = fechaSemana ORDER BY cheques_fecha asc limit 1), INTERVAL 7 day) AS hasta  from cheques_ventas
    where en_cartera='0' and cheques_ventas.cubierto='0'  and cheques_ventas.propio = '1'  and cheques_ventas.eliminado ='0'
    group by fechaSemana
    order by fechaSemana asc
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema reside en que la función `WEEK()` contiene un argumento extra, opcional, con el que puedes especificarle que día de la semana es el primero (Domingo o Lunes) y que semana es la primera (0 o 1), por defecto te coge el primer día de la semana como domingo y la primera semana la 0.

Si te fijas, el problema lo tienes con los domingos justo... eso es por lo que te he comentado, el primer día de la semana es domingo, así que el domingo empieza nueva semana.

Te adjunto un post que te explica esto, las opciones que tienes y algunos ejemplos para que veas.

[Mysql Week Function](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-week-function.php)

Yo creo que la que más te conviene es la opción `3`, esto es simplemente una opinión.